# How to select a value from CSV in an asp.net ajax toolbox autocomplete and pass that value to other textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have used Ajax toolkit autocomplete working fine using the following asp.net and C# code.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlMedicineName" runat="server" >
  <ContentTemplate>
           Name<br />
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtMedName" runat="server" Width="150px" 
                   ontextchanged="txtMedName_TextChanged"></TextBox>
  <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txtSearchID_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server"    DelimiterCharacters="" OnClientItemSelected="ItemSelected" Enabled="True" GetMedicine" ServicePath="Search/NameSearch.asmx" TargetControlID="txtMedName" MinimumPrefixLength="1">
 </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

My code Behind is :

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetMedicine(string prefixText)
{
 List<string> listString = new List<string>();
 using (SqlConnection con = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NewLandConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
 SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select ProductName+','+ProductCode+',' + (select unitName from Unit where Unit.Id=product1.UnitId) as ProductDetails,ProductId from product1 where ProductName like '"+prefixText+"%'", con);
 con.Open();
 SqlDataAdapter adr = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 adr.Fill(dt);
  for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            string countProduct = dt.Rows[j]["ProductDetails"].ToString();

           listString.Add(AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(dt.Rows[j]["ProductDetails"].ToString(),dt.Rows[j]["ProductId"].ToString()));
        }
  }
    string[] strarray = listString.ToArray();
    return strarray;
 }
```

Now when my auto complete works i get values in the form of : somename,code,unit
but i want that if a value is selected then i must get only the first value from csv i.e "somename" in that texbox and other two values(i.e code,unit ) must be populated in other texboxes respectively.

Please, help me in achieving this task.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, got the solution myself and with the help of   [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519311/how-can-i-add-selected-value-in-an-asp-net-ajax-toolbox-autocomplete-to-a-label)  , hope this would help someone also.So, I'm providing the code below for my above query:

```
OnClientItemSelected on the AutoCompleteExtender control run a javascript function

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function ItemSelected(sender, args) {
        __doPostBack(sender.get_element().name, "");
    }
</script>
```

Now on text change of the TextBox(AutoExtender) :

```
 Put the below code on textchange event

    string obj = txtMedName.Text.ToString();//in this texbox you are getting your 
                  //values from autoextender and so store this value in to a string
    string[] nameList = obj.Split(','); //finally using split separate your CSV 
                                    //values and store in an array which you are 
                                    // getting on autoextender
    txtMedName.Text = nameList[0].ToString();//Now pass the values to respective 
                                             //texboxes
    txtBox2.Text = nameList[1].ToString();
    txtBox3.Text = nameList[2].ToString();
```